# How to load ViewModel from LINQ and pass it to View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

How can we pass following `ViewModel` - that is loaded via `LINQ` query's **Select Statement** - to a View. I'm getting the error shown below. **Please note** that I still want to load ViewModel via select statement of LINQ query:

**Model**:

```
Public class Customer
{
  Public int CustomerId {get; set;}
  Public string FullName {get; set;}
  ...
}

Public class Order
{
  Public int OrderId {get; set;}
  Public int CustomerId {get; set;}
  Public float Price {get; set;}
  ...
}
```

**ViewModel:**

```
Public class CustomViewModel
{
  Public String Name {get; set;}
  Public float Price {get; set;}
  ...
}
```

**View**:

```
@model myProject.Models.CustomViewModel
...
```

**Controller**:

```
var qry = from c in _context.Customers
          join o in context.Orders on c.CustomerId = o.CustomerId
          select new CustomViewModel { Name = c.FullName, Price = o.Price  };

return View(qry);
```

**Error**:

> The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1[myProject.Models.CustomViewModel]. But this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'myProject.Models.CustomViewModel]'

Comment: context._Customers is a list. Do you want the view to show a list or do you want to show a specific customer?

Comment: Your view is for a single `CustomViewModel` - its thats what you want then use `.FirstOrDefault()` in your query. (2nd code snippet in the dupe)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thank for catching it. I had originally missed the second table in the post. I've added it now along with corresponding changes in the `ViewModel` and `LINQ` query

Comment: @NineBerry To answer your question, please see my comment above

Comment: Your edit makes no difference to the issue. You query is generating a collection of `CustomViewModel`, not a single `CustomViewModel`. Either your view needs to be `@model IEnumerable<CustomViewModel>` to match the query, or if you want to have the view display just one item, then use `.FirstOrDefault()` to return one item. And do not use `var`!

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks. After reading your comment, I used `.SingleOrDefault()` and it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing to your view an `IQueryable<CustomViewModel>` not an instance of `CustomViewModel` as you intended to do. I think you want to get the list of names, so you should change the model type in your view to

```
@model IEnumerable<myProject.Models.CustomViewModel>
```

And also you should materialize your query before passing the result to your view:

```
return View(qry.ToList());
```

Otherwise when you try to hit the result of your query in your view, your `DbContext` will be disposed, so and an exception will be thrown.

### Update

If you want to show the info related to one particular customer then I suggest you to use [`FirstOrDefault`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549141(v=vs.110).aspx) extension method:

```
return View(qry.FirstOrDefault());
```

Comment: Sorry I missed the second table in the POST. I've added it now along with the corresponding changes in the VM and LINQ query. You may want to modify your response accordingly.

Comment: But in the View I just need to display a data about a single customer not a list.

Comment: Then you you should call [FirstOrDefault](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549141(v=vs.110).aspx) method at the end of your query to select the customer you want to show,eg, `View(qry.FirstOrDefault());`